# Could not Retrieve the wsdl file in eclipse Apache Axis2

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, uri, apache-axis

I am trying to consume a soap web service using wsdl file. In eclipse when I try  New>Other>Web Service Client> Service definition : `http://abc.com/demo?wsdl&username=test&password=test`

I get an error:

```
Could not Retrieve the wsdl file http://abc.com/demo?wsdlusername=testpassword=test
```

When it shows the error -  it doesn't show '&' in uri. Do I need to put some encoding ?  I tried putting wsdl somewhere else so I don't have to use username & password - that worked.  Also, The URL working in browser.  Can you please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`wsimport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) tool that is included in the JDK 6 or higher? e.g.:

```
wsimport http://abc.com/demo?wsdl&username=test&password=test -Xnocompile
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I was too quick - this doesn't work as well. takes me to login page. however this works in the Browser